# remove unwanted tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup4 for some web scraping project. However, the code return more stuff than intended. For example the below are also return. How to I eliminate them? I have already tried simple housekeeping methods.

As seen from my code I have already added in 'style' to be removed, but it still appear under the results. I'm not sure why is this so.

```
    # Remove unwanted tag elements:
    cleaned_text = ''
    blacklist = [
        '[document]', 
        'noscript',
        'header',
        'html',
        'meta',
        'head', 
        'input',
        'script',
        'style',]

    # Then we will loop over every item in the extract text and make sure that the beautifulsoup4 tag
    # is NOT in the blacklist
    for item in text:
        if item.parent.name not in blacklist:
            cleaned_text += '{} '.format(item)
            
    # Remove any tab separation and strip the text:
    cleaned_text = cleaned_text.replace('\t', '')
    return cleaned_text.strip()
```

below are unnecessary results that need to be removed.

```
 [if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif] [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:RelyOnVML/>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif] [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves/>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:DontVertAlignInTxbx/>
   <w:Word11KerningPairs/>
   <w:CachedColBalance/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="--"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif] [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="267">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>

 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif] [if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
 {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
 mso-para-margin-right:0in;
 mso-para-margin-bottom:10.0pt;
 mso-para-margin-left:0in;
 line-height:115%;
 mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
 mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;

</style>
<![endif]
```

Comment: you only check if the parent name is in the blacklist. just check `item.name`. and maybe you'd go faster checking directly `soup.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I print out the item.parent.name and manually inspect each value and remove accordingly. Similar to what diggusbickus mentioned.